# How to make JsHint sbt plugin more useful?

Tags: jshint, sbt-plugin, playframework-2.4

When I have jshint sbt plugin enable in my Play project, I get these annoying errors which are really not errors. How can I turn them off, or avoid them?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jshint is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.  You can configure its errors with a standard `.jshintrc` file in the project root.

The first error exists because it should be `window.alert(s)`.